# android webview error . findViewbyID

Tags: android, webview

Newbie on mobile apps.
I'm trying to use webview on my android app. But there is a problem in my code. I used the example from https://developer.android.com/ but its now working somehow. Can you please check my code....

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

android says "cannot resolve symbol webview"...

whole code is here ->

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); // here is the problem
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: Did you assign an id to the webView in your xml? Please post the xml as well.

Comment: <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.weburl.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Please edit your question and put this xml code there for better understanding of others who see this question. :)

Comment: Hi! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes to your webView in xml:

```
<WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" 
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/webview"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have a WebView in your `activity_main.xml` with an `id` attribute with value `@+id/webview` like in the example below:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```